# CCActionMoveTo Is it possible to add an effect like scaleTo or lighting to an sprite, while the acction "CCActionMoveTo" is taking effect

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to implement an animation that uses the moveTO action. Basically the animation is a movement of an sprite from left to Right. What i need to to is set an scaleTO while the sprite  is moving...

```
CCActionMoveTo   *move = [CCActionMoveTo actionWithDuration:1.00f position:destination];
CCActionScaleTo  *scale= [CCActionScaleTo actionWithDuration:0.1 scale:1.5];  
CCActionSequence *seq. = [CCActionSequence actions:move ,scale,NULL];
```

As you can see i use sequence, but is not working, because the executes in the specific order. and i need to scale the sprite while is moving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use a spawn. Depending on which cocos2d you are using determines what this looks like. For example in v3:

```
CCActionMoveTo* move = [CCActionMoveTo actionWithDuration:1.0f position:ccp(100.0f, 0.0f)];
CCActionScaleTo* scale = [CCActionScaleTo actionWithDuration:1.0f scale:1.5f];
CCActionSpawn * moveAndScale = [CCActionSpawn actions:move, scale, nil];

CCSprite* sprite = ...;
[sprite runAction:moveAndScale];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Exactly i'm using V3.. will try the actionSpaw.Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

declare the action first.

```
CCActionMoveTo* move = [CCActionMoveTo actionWithDuration:1.0 position:destination];


CCActionScaleTo* scaling = [CCActionScaleTo actionWithDuration:0.1 scale:1.5];
```

make a sequence

```
CCActionSpawn * moveAndScale = [CCActionSpawn actions: moving, scaling, nil];
```

then run them all

```
[sprite runAction: moveAndScale];
```

Answer (score 1):

Run them individually:

```
CCActionMoveTo* move = [CCActionMoveTo actionWithDuration:1.0 position:destination];
[sprite runAction:move];

CCActionScaleTo* scale = [CCActionScaleTo actionWithDuration:0.1 scale:1.5];  
[sprite runAction:scale];
```

If you need to start scale at a later time:

```
CCActionMoveTo* move = [CCActionMoveTo actionWithDuration:1.0 position:destination];
[sprite runAction:move];

id delay = [CCActionDelay actionWithDuration:0.6];  
CCActionScaleTo* scale = [CCActionScaleTo actionWithDuration:0.1 scale:1.5];  
id seq = [CCActionSequence actions:delay, scale, nil];
[sprite runAction:seq];
```

Comment: Note that, if you want no delay -- that is, if you just want it to move & scale at the same time -- you just call the two `[sprite runAction: <whatever>]` calls one after the other.  Any actions triggered will run for their duration beginning at the time of the call, and multiple actions stack, so you can move, rotate, scale, etc. all at once with `[sprite runAction: moveAction]; [sprite runAction: scaleAction]; [sprite runAction: rotAction];`